# Overriding Django's RelatedManager methods

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django's `ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor.create_manager(...)` function dynamically creates the `RelatedManager` classes and subsequently initializes an instance of the dynamically created class.

If I wanted to override the `RelatedManager.add(...)` method, how would I do it?

The `RelatedManager` classes are created in file: `django/db/models/fields/related.py`.

An example of how I'd like to use a custom `RelatedManager` is...

```
class Record(Model):
    string = CharField()
class Managed(Model):
    record = ForeignKey('Record')
    boolean = BooleanField()
def view_function(...):
    record = Record(string='Example')
    record.save()
    record.managed_set.add(Managed(boolean=True)) # How to override add()?
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you need the override for - the default queryset already does what you want.

But to answer the question, you can define a custom Manager on the model and set `use_for_related_fields=True` to ensure it gets used as the automatic manager. See the documentation on [controlling automatic Manager types](http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.X/topics/db/managers.html#controlling-automatic-manager-types).

Comment: man, you're my django guru round these parts, you know everything

Comment: This doesn't work. Creating a custom Manager which sets use_for_related_fields = True ensures that the RelatedManager's superclass is the custom Manager. However, the RelatedManager class is defined dynamically in the file specified in my question and any add() in the custom Manager is overridden by the dynamic definition of RelatedManager.  I may modify RelatedManager's add() and add self.pre_save() and self.post_save() hooks to be implemented within custom Managers and then submit a patch to Django, but I'm wondering if there is a better way I'm not aware of.

Comment: -1 as it does not work, the '_related_' in that variable is just piece of history and has nothing to do with managers of related fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am having the same problem.

I have a custom manager that overrides `self._db` and `get_query_set()` to route it to different databases.

I dynamically created a *model* class, and has its `_default_manager` set with my custom manager.

This works for the class itself, but not for related field (foreign or many2many), even though I did set sets `use_for_related_fields = True`.

For related field, appending `db_manager(dbname)` (for example, `record.managed_set.db_manager(dbname)`) can fix *all()* method, but not for *add()* method.

To understand what I mean, see this django ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13358

I think it works for `all()`, but not `add()`.

Comment: why it doesn't work with `add()`? does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`RelatedManager.add()` calls `RelatedManager._add_items()` which calls `Manager.bulk_create()`.

So if you extend `Manager.bulk_create()`, you might be able to achieve what you are after.